# Can pf be used to modify HTTP Headers and Contents?

Tags: openbsd, pf

I'm looking at options to replace my router with something that offers me more options for content filtering and also content modification.

One of the things that I want to do is to modify HTTP Requests, e.g. Add or Remove certain Headers or the contents of the body (e.g., to remove any references to `ga.js`). Also, I want to block access to certain sub-paths of a domain, e.g. block `twitter.com/widgets` without blocking the main `twitter.com` website (in which case a custom DNS that returns 0.0.0.0 would do the job)

I'm wondering if PF on OpenBSD can do that, or if it's too low level and if I need a higher level tool like a proxy. The problem with using a proxy is that it's not transparent for clients and thus doesn't help e.g. protecting my phone while it's on my WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To PF or not to PF?

I do not believe `pf` is the appropriate place to filter a high level element such as `ga.js`. Rather it operates a layer or two below that. Filtering `ga.js` would be better suited to something such as a proxy package such as Squid.

*excerpt from [PF: Packet Filtering](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html)*

> Packet filtering is the selective passing or blocking of data packets as they pass through a network interface. The criteria that pf(4) uses when inspecting packets are based on the Layer 3 (IPv4 and IPv6) and Layer 4 (TCP, UDP, ICMP, and ICMPv6) headers. The most often used criteria are source and destination address, source and destination port, and protocol.

If you're familiar with the OSI model and TCP/IP this diagram shows which layers PF would be working in and which layer your `ga.js` file would be accessible for filtering.

[image: ss #1]

So PF can operate at the **Transport** & **Internet** layers. To operate on something such as `ga.js` you'd need to operate at the **Application** layer, hence a proxy.

#### Squid setup

This tutorial should get you started with the setup and configuration of Squid, titled: [Web Filtering On Squid Proxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150412072142/https://www.howtoforge.com/web-filtering-on-squid-proxy).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm basically looking for a Layer 7 Firewall. Thanks for clarifying that PF is Layer 3/4, I'll see if I can find a way to make Squid transparent to clients (this seems promising: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html ) or if there are other Layer 7 filtering options.